# How to update contact images on an android phone using react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-contacts

I want to delete the images of all the contacts present in the android phone from my react-native app.

Initially, I was using react-native with Expo and hence used `expo-contacts` for accessing the contacts. But it doesn't have any method for editing contacts in an android phone automatically.  [updateContactAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/contacts/#contactsupdatecontactasynccontact) works for iOS only, and its android counterpart, [presentFormAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/contacts/#contactspresentformasynccontactid-contact-formoptions) opens a contact form for a single contact and needs input from the user to be saved.

I also created a bare react-native project, and tried the [react-native-contacts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-contacts) package. Used the `updateContact` method to set
`hasThumbnail` to false and `thumbnailPath` to null. It doesn't return an error but the contact image doesn't get deleted either. I double-checked the documentation and noticed these lines about the `addContact` and `openContactForm` methods

> **Adding Contacts**
>
> Currently all fields from the contact record except for thumbnailPath are supported for writing
>
> ...
>
> **Open Contact Form**
>
> Currently all fields from the contact record except for thumbnailPath are supported for writing

So I'm assuming the `updateContact` method also doesn't support updating contact images. I searched for other packages or ways to do this from react-native but couldn't find anything. Is this not possible currently or am I missing something?